# Independent Census Data for 3rd World Countries

Tags: data-request, data.gov, census

A standardized dataset for 3rd world countries, preferably younger than 10 years.

Comment: I am not share what you mean by independent? The UN maintains census data for all countries in the world, but the information is obtained from each country's Department of Statistics.

Comment: OP, keep in mind that data from some countries is just an estimate, but if that's all you have access to, that's what you'll have to use. Some governments have a lot of corruption and waste so many data in those countries is inaccurate, often in favor of the country in question.

Comment: have you looked at the open data census? not exactly what you want, but could be in the ballpark

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for ipums international.

https://international.ipums.org/international/

easiest to analyze with

http://www.asdfree.com/2015/11/laptop-friendly-analysis-of-census-of.html

Answer (score 2):

Both the United Nations Statistical Division and World Bank maintain databases related to population, and other vital statistics, for each country in the world. The data is collected from each country's equivalent of Department of Statistics.

UNSD: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/dyb/dybcensusdata.htm

World Bank:  http://data.worldbank.org

I (opengeocode) maintain our own versions of the datasets in linked CSV format using a common vocabulary (using our ETL process): http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.2/UN/index.php

Comment: OP: Try this one: http://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/Population-ranking-table